# How to detect if my code is running on WatchKit or iOS using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I have a class with both targets, and I want to know if I'm running it's methods on Watch or iPhone target.

Please, just Swift answers.

Comment: Wait, you don't know where you call the method? Or maybe you want to make it 'behave' differently depending on where it's called. If that's the case, it probably should not be the same method or class, or just parametrize it.

Comment: I'm building a "man in the middle" between watch and iphone communication, and the code is almost the same, I want to check for that condition in order to make proper changes in behaviour

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something like this

```
#if os(iOS)
  print("iOS")
#else 
  print("anything else")
#endif
```

Or even this

```
if #available(watchOS 2,*){}
if #available(iOS 9, *){}
```